# How do I join elements of tuples of a list through list comprehension

Tags: python, tuples, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

I have a list containing tuples of three elements which contain e-mail data.

```
email_data = [('jbd', 'email', '.com'), ('my_jbd', 'my_site', '.com')]
```

What I am trying to attain is to join three elements of each tuple and get email
address like 'jbd@email.com' and for that I am using list comprehension as under:

```
email_list = [  (y+'@', y) [i!=0] for x in result for i, y in enumerate(x) ]
print( email_list ) # ['jbd@', 'email', '.com', 'my_jbd@', 'my_site', '.com']
```

What I exactly require is list like this -> ['jbd@email.com', 'my_jbd@my_site.com'].
Since, I am a beginner in Python, I am clueless as to how do I join these tuple
elements within list comprehension and get a list containing email data. Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `format` method.

```
email_list = ["{}@{}{}".format(*t) for t in email_data]
```

Comment: perhaps an f-string version might be useful as well. So maybe `[f"{username}@{domain}{suffix} for username, domain, suffix in email_data]`

Comment: I'd be more likely to bother naming the unpacked elements if they were used out of order, say `{3}@{1}{2}.format(*t)` or something like that. Without more context, which one I would use would probably depend on what day of the week it was :)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
email_data=[i[0]+"@"+i[1]+i[2] for i in email_data]
print(email_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```py
[f'{el[0]}@{el[1]}{el[2]}' for el in email_data]
```

What we are doing here is using a format string to pass in each tuple which we are naming 'el' in the list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
email_data = [('jbd', 'email', '.com'), ('my_jbd', 'my_site', '.com')]
for i in email_data :
    s = i[0] + '@'+''.join(i[1:])
    print(s)
```